# Can't figure out how to pass arguments to argparse

Tags: python, command-line, argparse, spyder

I'm going through the docs on the argparse module and I can't figure out how to get the same results as explained in the docs.  You can either specify the arguments on the command-line, or it allows you to specify them within parse_args() which is helpful for testing.  Here is an example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.parse_args('--foo 1'.split())
```

That is directly from the docs here:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#action

It is supposed to output this:

```
Namespace(foo='1')
```

But this is what I get:

```
Namespace(foo=None)
```

I also tried the following:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--bar', action='store_false')
parser.add_argument('--baz', action='store_false')
parser.parse_args(['--foo', '--bar'])
```

And that one outputs this:

```
Namespace(bar=True, baz=True, foo=False)
```

which is what it's supposed to do.  Can anyone tell me what's going on here?  Here is my full code that I used to generate the output for both snippets of code shown above:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.parse_args('--foo 1'.split())
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
#supposed to be Namespace(foo='1')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--bar', action='store_false')
parser.add_argument('--baz', action='store_false')
parser.parse_args(['--foo', '--bar'])
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
#supposed to be Namespace(foo=True, bar=False, baz=True)
```

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm doing this in Spyder 3.1.4 and I'm running Python 3.6.0

> UPDATE

Due to some ambiguity in the docs I didn't know how they got from setting the command-line arguments to displaying the output.  With the help of @hpaulj I realized all I was doing was displaying the output relative to arg.sysv instead of the specified custom command-line - oops!  Here's the corrected code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
#added this assignment to args
args = parser.parse_args('--foo 1'.split())
#following line was wrong - removing
#args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
#supposed to be Namespace(foo='1')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--bar', action='store_false')
parser.add_argument('--baz', action='store_false')
#added this assignment to args
args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', '--bar'])
#following line was wrong - removing
#args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
#supposed to be Namespace(foo=True, bar=False, baz=True)
```

Comment: Use `args=parser.parse_args('...'.split)`.  `args=parser.parse_args()` parses the commandline, not your test case.

Comment: Ohhh..... I see what you mean - lemme give that a try!

Comment: Oops.. so I was calling parse_args(...), only to call it again.  It's confusing because the docs don't actually tell you how to output, they just tell you the value of namespace.  I will update the question with the corrected version.  Thanks!!

Comment: The docs examples show what you'd see in an interactive python session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
args = parser.parse_args('--foo 1'.split())
print(args)
```

## This will give you your answer. You are trying to parse again thats why it was giving None

Comment: Yup, @hpaulj said the same up above and I updated my question accordingly.  Thanks!

Comment: Or maybe your answer came in first?  Sorry if I missed it!